# Need R function to manipulate two data frames

Tags: r, spotfire

Can I get some help writing an efficient R function for this situation?
I have a Summary and a detail table.  I would like to replace the values in the Summary table (or create another Output Table) with matching values in the Detail table based on some conditions.  I need help with R script that can accomplish the following:

a)  For each unique combination of (Name and Date) in the summary Table A

a.  Perform the following for matching records on Table B (Detail Table):

i.  If  sum of Value A = Sum of Value B then Copy/replace records with Detail

ii. If the sum of Value A is not equal to Sum of Value (B)

1. Find the difference
2. Add that difference to the Type “P” value in Table B to ensure that the sums match. .
3. Then copy to new table or replace the records (with the adjusted “P” value)  with the details.

Table A:

```
Name    Date    valueA
A   1/2/2016    21
A   1/3/2016    27
B   1/2/2016    50
```

Table B:

```
Name    Date    Type    ValueB
A   1/2/2016    F   10
A   1/2/2016    P   11
A   1/3/2016    F   12
A   1/3/2016    F   13
A   1/3/2016    P   2
B   1/2/2016    F   25
B   1/2/2016    P   12
```

Expected Output

```
Name    Date    Type    Value                   
A   1/2/2016    F   10                  
A   1/2/2016    P   11                  
A   1/3/2016    F   12                  
A   1/3/2016    F   13                  
A   1/3/2016    P   2                   
B   1/2/2016    F   25                  
B   1/2/2016    P   25  <<-- Adjust Values of "P" type with the difference
```

Comment: Figure this out yet? I think it can be done with transformations if not.

Comment: Ok...how do I iterate through the rows without a script ... but if I can easily process thousands of records with a transformation ... please let me know how.  Thanks.